# Regex Autohotkey

Tags: regex, xml, autohotkey

Im currently making a script to delete text from a document.

The text that have to be deleted:

```
            <ForeignTable Name="JobPlan" Alias="FK0024">
                <Fields>
                    <Field Name="JpDescr" Alias="F24000" />
                </Fields>
                <MaskInfo Rights="Add" AddContext="1">
                    <ContextStatus Context="1" Status="0" Update="True" />
                </MaskInfo>
            </ForeignTable>
```

But the problem is that the Alias and Context most of the time not the same value contains.

EDIT: So i want to delete from `<ForeignTable` to `</ForeignTable>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the regex pattern `<ForeignTable(.|\n|\r\n)*?<\/ForeignTable>`
Should match any occurrences in a document of what you have above.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/k4GedG/1/